# How put a cordova plugin without breaking everything?

Tags: cordova, plugins, version-control

I'm trying to add the cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin on my app, everything works, but after i install the plugin, the build crashes.

I thought on changing the minSdkVersion of plugin to 19 on plugin.xml, but it doesn't work. Everything worked before i added the plugin.

> > Task :app:processReleaseManifest FAILED
>
> See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information
>   about the manifest merger.
>
> /home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-74
>   Error:    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 19
>   declared in library [:CordovaLib]
>   /home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/library_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 15    Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,         or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 19,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to
>   runtime failures)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
>
>   > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib]
>   >     /home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/library_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml
>   >     as the library might be using APIs not available in 15    Suggestion:
>   >     use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>   >           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
>   >           or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 49s 28 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 2 up-to-date
>   /home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/gradlew: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output: Note:
>   /home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. /home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-74
>   Error:    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 19
>   declared in library [:CordovaLib]
>   /home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/library_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 15    Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,         or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 19,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to
>   runtime failures)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
>
>   > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib]
>   >     /home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/library_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml
>   >     as the library might be using APIs not available in 15    Suggestion:
>   >     use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>   >           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
>   >           or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 49s
>
> app:spawn Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1 +0ms 
>   app:cordova-conf ⚠️  [FAIL] Cordova CLI has failed +1ms

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the url: `/home/usuario/kmais-app/src-cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/`. That's not your cordova project, that is CordovaLib (Cordova Android).

`cordova-android` has its own `AndroidManifest`, your `AndroidManifest` would be located at `src/main/AndroidManifest` and you're correctly raising the `minimumSdkVersion` of that.

Update your `cordova-android` version to upgrade `minSdkVersion` of that.